# LV cable sizing for short circuit condition (NEC)

Tags: power, cables

Do we need to perform short circuit condition i.e let through energy condition while sizing the LV cables as per NEC (National Electrical Code)?

Answer (score 1):

I assue you are in the US. Perhaps not.
 I do not know the **regulatory** needs for NEC (National Electric Code) design, not having waded through the documentation below, but design sizing would not usually be associated with testing in any way.
 Design is usually a matter of using tables or calculators or performing calculations and applying relevant requlatory  codes.

After installation you "will need to" [tm] test the installation, but that is another issue.

---

Liable to be very useful [Complicated attempt to simplify confusing NEC requirements](http://www.mjobee.com/projects&news/NEC%20Art%20310.15.pdf)

[Cable sizing table {NEC extract}](http://lugsdirect.com/WireCurrentAmpacitiesNEC-Table-301-16.htm)

Here is a [useful online NEC cable sizing calculator](http://www.paigewire.com/calculatorinstructions.htm)

[Another NEC cable sizing calculator](http://www.electrician2.com/calculators/wireocpd_ver_1.html)

Sizing tables [here](http://www.affordable-solar.com/Learning-Center/Solar-Tools/wire-sizing) - solar emphasis.

Advice [and sales pitch for their software here](http://www.dolphins-software.com/PDF/CableSizing.pdf)
 Why they, and others, think you may want expert assistance:

[image]

---

[Basic NEC design rules here](http://www.fs.fed.us/database/acad/elec/greenbook/3_basicdesigns.pdf)

[Simplified guidelines for Joe average](http://www.ehow.com/how_5943504_choose-cable-size-electrical-run.html)

---

Related:

[Very nice Belden cable catalog](http://www.belden.com/products/catalogs/mastercatalog/brilliance/upload/22Technical_Information.pdf)

[Cable fire ratings](http://www.cablesplususa.com/cable-info/nav-jacket-rating.php) brief

[Fire alarm cable specifics](http://ulstandardsinfonet.ul.com/scopes/1424.html)

[Cable fire testing](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/fam.810160302/abstract)

[Cable flame testing](http://www.distributorwire.com/products/cable-flame-test.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information .. while sizing Lv cables as per IEC conidtions for short circuit & If for 5 sec are checked but the same is not done in NEC.Why so?

Comment: @ShwetaKhullar - Standards are as standards writers make them :-). If it's in the requirement you must do it. If it's not then you can consider if it is useful to do it, as long as the standard does not forbid it.